# Moving source files in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2

How can I move source files physically from one folder to another, and tell Xcode 4.2 the new path to those files?

Comment: Useful tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414181/moving-files-into-a-real-folder-in-xcode

Answer (score 5):

See The Xcode hierarchy is a purely visual organization system. It has no effect on your actual file hierarchy. Xcode leaves the actual file system up to you.

Thus, you could, if you wanted to, have one folder on disk with all your source files, resources, etc. And then, in Xcode, you could have an elaborately organized hierarchy to display your source files.

To get your things done first Make a copy of files in desired directory. Then remove all those files from the Xcode Project. Then add the existing files from new directory and this way you can get Xcode to link to new directory.

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your solution.

I created aproject X and later on, a view controller with 2 files XViewController.h and XViewController.m inside this project. Those files (by some mistake) were not created inside the physical+xcodevirtual project folder X, but in the root folder that contained X. 
When I moved those files from inside Xcode to the X folder, the files seem that they moved there under X and they showed up there in the project hierarchy.

However, this way I ended up with 2 physical copies of them, on at the same level as X physical folder, and another under X.

After adding a property in the XViewController.h and build the project I noticed that my change did not work, and the Xcode reported the error that there was no such property inside the XViewController class and in the .h file.

Using "Show in finder" option I found the real file. Then I copied the updated physical files under X physical folder and delete the files that were in the same directory level as X. That way the Xcode project references to these files became red, implying that the virtual environment had lost the files. So, I completely deleted them from inside Xcode.

Then using File --> "Add Files to X..." menu option I re-connect the "good" physical files to my project X, and this messing problem was solved.