# objective c iOS file structure confusion

Tags: ios, xcode, file, filesystems, nsbundle

I'm just new to iOS and am really confused by how files are managed.

In my project, I have set up directories, so I have in xcode:

Supporting Files
 . Set 1
    ..pic0101N.png
    ..pic0102N.png
 . Set 2
    ..pic0201N.png
    ..pic0202N.png
etc..

Also in the file structure where my app is (on my Desktop in a folder named FTF), I have a directory named images and a subdirectories for Set 1, Set 2, etc

When I click on an image in Xcode, the full path is listed as: /Users/MyName/Desktop/FTF/FTF/images/Set 1/pic0101N.png

My question is, how do I get a list of all the images in the Set 1 folder?

I've tried the various ways of using:
[NSBundle mainBundle] but, it all boils down to that my path seems to be:

/Users/MyName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/Axxxx1E9-19B3-XXX-XXXX-xxX5xXxX4x9/FTF.app

And that there doesn't seem to be any of my file structure in here, like the files are in there but not in any directories, they all just seem to be a bunch of files in there.

NSArray *namesArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@""];

yields a list of all the PNGS as such:
/Users/MyName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/Axxx81E9-19B3-4B4D-9FD4-XXXXX4499/FTF.app/pic0101N.png
/Users/MyName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/AXX9-19B3-4B4D-9FD4-8x9xx4499/FTF.app/pic0101P.png

I think I must have a fundamental confusion of what is going on. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

That's because Xcode is being unhelpful (and/or it assumes that the developer is dumb or something) and whenever you create a group, it's only reflected in the project structure - no corresponding folders are physically created on the filesystem.

If you want to get yourself real folders, that's also possible - refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414181/moving-files-into-a-real-folder-in-xcode).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had a go at the tips in that response and was indeed able to move files around in xcode and finder, but still getting the same result of

NSArray *namesArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@""];

Giving a flat list:
/Users/MyName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/Axxx81E9-19B3-4B4D-9FD4-XXXXX4499/FTF.app/pic0101N.png /Users/MyName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/AXX9-19B3-4B4D-9FD4-8x9xx4499/FTF.app/pic0101P.png

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is the difference between the Xcode project structure, the MAC OS X file system structure, the iOS app file system structure and what files are actually copied to the app during build.

For a start, having files in a location on Mac OS X doesn't mean they will be in any kind of similar location in the project or the app.

The iOS app is a bundle of contents ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)), some of which is not editable and is set by Xcode when building the app and some of which is able to be written to (like the app documents directory). The files that are copied to the app are controlled by the `build phases` settings in Xcode.

The way you are using `NSBundle` is the correct way to find and use resources that were copied to the app during the build.