# Legacy iOS app didn't use folder structure for it's files at all. How to refactor without individually telling each file where it now lives?

Tags: ios, xcode, refactoring

I have inherited an iOS app where all the class files were dumped into the root directory.  In the project there are groups but the files themselves are not in folders.

How do I go about refactoring and redoing the project so I can create folders and put the files into them, without having to manually tell each file where it now lives in the xcode sidebar.

I'm going to assume there's some sort of 'auto-scan for files' feature but I'm worried that this could end up causing all sorts of compilation issues.

If there's a safe way to do this appreciate the help!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414181/moving-files-into-a-real-folder-in-xcode

Comment: That's both the answer I was looking for and the one I was hoping I wouldn't find.  Thank you. :)